# copy assignment operator definition

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

what would be the definition of copy assignment operator of a class if a class having const member variable and a reference member variable 
eg:

```
class ABC
{
  int const i;
  int & j;
  int k;
  public :
  ABC() :k(40), i(10),j(k)
  {}
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of having a reference to a member variable?

Comment: its not reference to member variable , its simply reference i put a example in the constructor only

Comment: 1.what if i have a class having only a const member variable

Comment: @SanjaySingh - What the reference refers to has a great implication on whether copy assignment can exist and how it would look. So it's not a small detail you can omit.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're right, there is no need modifying `j` when assigning here

Comment: 2. and a class having only a reference member variable

Comment: What do you want the assignment operator to do?

Comment: @SanjaySingh - The answer is "depends". There is no 1 always true solution. This seems too broad to me now

Comment: @SanjaySingh: Please place your questions in the question.

Comment: simply the basic function ( copying an object with the existing one).

Comment: "simply the basic function" the most simple way to copy an object is to default construct a new one and not care about the original. Whether you would call this a "copy" is up to you, but it is definitely the most simple way. In any case it is always completely up to you to define what it means to copy an object

Comment: what if their is code like this :
int main()
{
ABC a1,a2;
a1=a2;}

Comment: If all instances have the same value for the `const` member, then make it `static constexpr` instead: `static constexpr int = 10;` For the reference, use a pointer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Const objects and references are non-assignable. Therefore a class that has such members will not have implicit assignment operators. It is possible to define a custom assignment operator, but not in a way that modifies those members.

If you want your class to have a copy assignment that makes the reference to refer to the same object as was referred by the argument object, then you simply cannot use a reference for that purpose.

If you want your class to have a copy assignment that makes a const member to have the same value as the argument object, then you simply cannot use a const member.

> for const we can do it with the help of const_cast

Modifying a const object (with help of `const_cast`) has undefined behaviour.

Comment: for const we can do it with the help of const_cast  , but for reference i don't know the code

Comment: @SanjaySingh no, you cannot do that with the help of const_cast. It's good that you don't *know the code*, since the code does not exist. It is something prohibited by the language.